# Stop a notification using swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, localnotification, cancellation

I have a problem which involves stopping a local notification. This stop button is that so if the user starts a timer (a notification pops up once the timer runs out) and then decides they no longer need the timer, they can cancel it. The problem here is that every method I've tried does not stop the notification from going off. This is mostly because the methods are out of date. Below is my code and I was wondering whether anyone had any ideas on how to stop the notification from going off. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
//In the view did load section
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("granted")
        } else {
            print("not granted")
        }
    }


//in a seperate function
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

content.title = "Local notification"
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "1.mp3")
content.badge = 1

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: time, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "requestAlarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
center.add(request)

center.delegate = self
```

Comment: I don't see any cancellation code.

Comment: Yes, I have removed it because as I mentioned it was all in general depreciated in IOS 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the user notification center to `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests`.

Comment: Do I add that as it is in a function or?

Comment: Ok I have the answer thank you very much for your help :) I used centre.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

Answer (score 1):

You can stop certain notification with:

```
center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["alarm"])
```

Where "alarm" is your categoryIdentifier. This way you won't stop every notification, just the chosen one. Good stuff.
Regards.